# Specify freeDiameter source port

Tags: diameter-protocol, free-diameter

I'm getting started with freeDiameter. I have gone through docs over and over but didn't find any configuration variable to set the source port for when connection as a client.

My goal is to connect to HSS which requires the source port of my outgoing SCTP to be 3893 and destination port to be 3868.

Is there any configuration variable that I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

We can only configure the server side port in 'freediameter'.
when we create a client socket,system will assign a port as source port.
if u want to specify the portof client,u should use `bind()` to bind the port(3893) with u client socket.

Comment: can you please explain?. where to use bind(). You mean changing source?